# Weird behaviour when writing to excel with oledb

Tags: c#, excel, insert, oledb

I'm just trying to write anything to a cell but it looks like row count is incrementing even if the cell is empty. For example I have 20 cells filled in column F1. I insert in F1, now it has 21 cells filled. Then I try to insert in F2 which has empty cells beneath it, but it writes to F2:22. Isn't it supposed to insert to F2:1? I hope I am clear.

Here is the code:

```
string conStr = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\\sample.xls';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
OleDbConnection oleDbCon = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
oleDbCon.Open();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
myCommand.Connection = oleDbCon;
string sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (abc) values ('value')";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
oleDbCon.Close();
```

Comment: If you INSERT to a database, you get a new row, why should Excel be different?  You might need UPDATE/

Comment: That's what I feared. Ok, thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the software tool you are creating? Or is this simply a tutorial?

Comment: How do you intend to grab the value to add to your Spreadsheet, will this be done with a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

My Colleague Juliusz is correct: each sheet is, indeed, treated as a data table...

But that's not the only way to define a 'table' in Excel: you can query a named range or an explicitly specified address within a workbook:

```
    SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:F255]
```

If the Workbook contains a named range 'MyTable', defined as '=Sheet1!A1:F255' then can be queried as shown:

```
    SELECT * FROM [MyTable]
```

I would recommend that you test your insertion on a defined range with some identifiable data in it, so that you can see exactly what is happening.

Oh, and a word to the wise: see if running this query is creating hidden instances of Excel.Exe or using far more memory than you would expect... And check that this is being cleaned up properly on exit.

Answer (score 0):

Each sheet is treated as a database table, so any operations on it is done on the set basis. As Steve Wellens pointed out if you would like to put a value to column F2 on the same sheet you would need to use UPDATE syntax.

The other option is to create a new sheet and put values there through INSERT. Finally you can add another sheet which could merge those results together (which would behave like VIEW in the SQL database)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what your doing above, you are adding a new row to your spreadsheet each time you perform this piece of code.

Using the INSERT command will do as you would expect, it will insert a new row, even if you have attempeted to add data with no value.

If you want to get round this, check that the value your adding isn't null or equal to "" before you call this piece of code.

If you are using a GUI, check the value before submitting the changes back to the Spreadsheet.